# Is 'much better' correct usage?

Tags: meaning

We say much is Positive degree and Better is comparative. How can they be combined?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "much better" (and, in general, much + comparative) is correct usage.

Some examples:

Today I'm feeling much better than yesterday.
A snail is much smaller than an elephant.

Answer (score 2):

Comparatives adjectives that end with "er" like "Better" can be followed by much, a lot, far, a little, a bit, slightly.

> "Bob is much richer than I am"
>
> "My mother's hair is slightly longer than mine"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to combine them. The combination makes *much better*.

In general, you can add *much* to the comparative adjectives.

Answer (score 0):

Per point 8 [here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/much) much better translates to Considerably.

How are you feeling today? 
Day 1: I am feeling better, thanks. (Translation : I am not completely alright, but I sincerely appreciate your concern, Thank You for asking)
Day 2: I am feeling much better.(There has been considerable improvement in my health, I am feeling relieved!)